# scala collection functions different ways to call

Tags: scala

This compiles

```
//legal
def s1 = List("aaa","bbb").collect { case x => x.split("\\w") }
```

The following don't.

```
// all illegal

// missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => x$2.split{<null>}("\\w"{<null>} {<null>}){<null>}
def s2 = List("aaa","bbb").collect ( _.split("\\w") )

// missing parameter type
def s3 = List("aaa","bbb").collect ( x => x.split("\\w") )

// type mismatch; found : String => Array[java.lang.String] required: PartialFunction[java.lang.String,?]
def s4 = List("aaa","bbb").collect ( (x:String) => x.split("\\w") )
```

And whilst the scala compiler is doing his best to communicate with me where my errors lie, it's going right over my head.

The fact that this also compiles

```
def s2 = List("aaa","bbb").find ( _.split("\\w").length > 2 )
```

makes it all the more confusing when to use what

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why second part does not compile is that `List#collect` takes `PartialFunction[A, B]` as a param so it is possible to specify function to apply and filter elements that you what this function to be applied.

For example:

> List(1, "a", 2, "3").collect {case x : Int => x + 1 }

will be applied only to integer elements and return `List(2, 3)` which is `List[Int]`

In your case you can use `map` and `filter` functions to do the work

`def s1 = List("aaa","bbb").map(_.split("\\w")).filter(_.length > 2)`

Comment: Ok so it actually is a special case, in that it has a different signature than a method like find. I can live with that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

collect expects a partial function (series of case statements):

```
list.collect {
  case a => ...
  case b => ...
  ...
}
```